# Chapters in ClassicThesis' table of content are not uppercase

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters, classicthesis, uppercase, arsclassica

I am currently trying to use the latest version of `ClassicThesis` (with `ArsClassica` style), but I have some problems with the look of some elements in the table of content.

In the showcase example that is provided [on the home page of this package](https://bitbucket.org/amiede/classicthesis/wiki/Home), in the table of contents we can see that parts, chapters, appendix and bibliography are all uppercase, but if I compile that project, they will not be as such. How can I make them look like they appear in the example `.pdf`, i.e. uppercased?

Here is an example that you can easily compile:

```
\documentclass[twoside, openright, titlepage, numbers = noenddot,
headinclude, footinclude, cleardoublepage = empty,
abstract = on, BCOR = 5mm, paper = a4, fontsize = 11pt]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[eulerchapternumbers, eulermath, beramono, palatino, style = arsclassica]{classicthesis}

\begin{document}
\frenchspacing
\raggedbottom

\tableofcontents

\chapter{I am a chapter} % This should be uppercase!
\lipsum[1]

\section{I am a section}
\lipsum[1]

\subsection{And I am a subsection}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

I downloaded and compiled the example project provided with `version 4.2` and everything looks as it should, but since I am not an expert in LaTex programming, I do not know how to force the same behavior in its latest version.

Comment: Welcome. // Because Latex is powerful, i.e. complex, and your documentclass will be known by only a few, I suggest preparing a little fake-document, which shows your problem. Once you have it, please EDIT your question and add your code. To minimize textblocks I suggest using package lipsum https://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum or blindtext. Thank you

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Maybe now it is a bit clearer. Forgive my English, but it is not my main language

Comment: There is a compatability issue with `scrreport` and `titlesec`, `tocloft` that `classicthesis` is using, you can see it in your log when you compile it, maybe that is causing your issue. Do you need to use `scrreport`?

Comment: I do not have to use that package, but in all the examples I saw `scrreprt` or one of its alternatives is used.

Comment: The easy solution is to use the optional (short) title, as in \chapter[I AM A CHAPTER]{I am a chapter}.  See also \uppercase and \MakeUppercase.

Comment: As the document is configured to typeset the chapter titles in uppercase, you can simply use `\chapter{\MakeUppercase{I am a chapter}}` as this will not change the contents and force TOC entry to be wrapped in `\MakeUppercase`.

Comment: @user691586 Thank you very much! I used your suggestion to fix this issue!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @user691586, I managed to fix the style of both chapters and bibliography with the following:

```latex
\newcommand{\tocFixedChapter}[1]{\chapter{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}}
\renewcommand{\tocEntry}[1]{\protect\numberline{}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}}
```

Now the result is also coherent with the `ArcClassica` package!

This problem can be considered solved. Thanks!

Comment: This had no effect for me. What fixed it was: `\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\spacedlowsmallcaps}`. I reported the problem upstream: https://bitbucket.org/amiede/classicthesis/issues/203/not-getting-small-caps-for-chapter-names