# classicthesis table of contents font and style do not match

Tags: fonts, table-of-contents, titlesec, tocloft, classicthesis

The table of content does not take the fonts and style set in classicthesis.sty. Monospace is not used.
I assume this is a problem with KOMA script and titlesec or tocloft?

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{classicthesis}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \part{A Part}
    \chapter{Introduction}
    \section{Test Section}
    \subsection{Test Subsection}
\end{document}
```

Result

[image: Result]

Edit: in the classicthesis.sty one finds

```
    \renewcommand{\cftpartaftersnum}{}%
    \renewcommand{\cftpartaftersnumb}{\spacedlowsmallcaps}%
    \setlength{\cftpartnumwidth}{\cftchapnumwidth}
    \renewcommand{\cftpartfont}{\color{CTtitle}\normalfont}%
```

with

```
      \DeclareRobustCommand{\spacedlowsmallcaps}[1]{\textls[80]{\ct@caps\MakeTextLowercase{#1}}}
      }{\relax}
```

Where the TOC should look like in the Package documentation.

[image: Expected]

Is there any work around? Thanks!

Solution: The answer in this post [Chapters in ClassicThesis' table of content are not uppercase](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/687467/chapters-in-classicthesis-table-of-content-are-not-uppercase) solves only the Chapter problem. Apparently parts work differently. I had to add

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\l@part}{#1}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}{}{}
\makeatother
```

in the preamble to make it work for parts as well.

Comment: Perhaps you should explain why you'd expect that style?

Comment: That's what it looks like in the package documentation and I would expect from the classicthesis.sty. I edited my question

Comment: The same happens with `report` instead of `scrreprt`, so it is definitely not a KOMA-Script problem but a `classicthesis` issue. Maybe an incompatibility with newer LaTeX kernels. BTW: `classicthesis` requires packages, that are known to be not really compatible with KOMA-Script classes. So for all issues, that do not occur when using a standard class, I would say: It is expected.